# H2 create linked table - driver class not found

Tags: java, oracle, intellij-idea, jdbc, h2

When I try the following in my in-memory H2 console:

```
create linked table tbl01
('', 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@linkToMyDB.com:port_num:db_name', 'my_userid', 'my_password', 'SCHEMA.TABLE')
```

I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`.

I'm working with `ojdbc6-12.1.0.2.jar`. I've already added it to the classpath:

```
java -cp /path/to/ojdbc6-12.1.0.2.jar oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 JDBC 4.0 compiled with JDK6 on Mon_Jun_30_11:28:06_PDT_2014
#Default Connection Properties Resource
#Fri Jun 07 11:17:29 PDT 2019
```

I can't do `java -cp /path/to/ojdbc6-12.1.0.2.jar oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` to point to the driver that the `create linked table` command is trying to reference since that class lacks the `main()` method.

Is there a way to force the first command to use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`? I've tried the following and get the same error:

```
create linked table tbl01
('oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver', 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@linktodb.com:port_num:db_name', 'my_userid', 'my_password', 'SCHEMA.TABLE')
```

I'm doing this on IntelliJ IDEA with an in-memory database trying to connect to a remote Oracle database.

Comment: I'm using the h2 console on the database view within IntelliJ IDEA. I'm pretty sure my application is independent of the database view console because the application doesn't need to be running for me to access the databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, whatever runs H2 is the relevant application (iirc IntelliJ launches a separate Java process for the database tooling), and you need to make sure that the Oracle JDBC driver is on its classpath.

You can do this by going to the H2 driver definition in IntelliJ (Database, Data Source Properties), and add the Oracle JDBC driver jar as a Custom JAR (not as a Provided Driver).